# python won't solve my equation how can I fix it?

Tags: python-3.x

```
    def my_function(parameter):
    print(parameter)
my_function("Maxwell Filipe")
my_function("Program 1 Projectile Motion Formulae")
my_function("2/9/2020")
my_function("Program that will solve simple Projectile Motion Equations")
my_function("Choose the values for time, yVelocity, and xVelocity")
time = input()
g = 9.8
yVelocity = input()
units='m/s'
xVelocity = input()
import math
solve(yVelocity*time-.5*g*t**2)
solve(xVelocity*time)
solve(yVelocity-g*t)
```

This is my code and my first assignment for my class and i'm completely stuck and I get an error  message when it goes to solve the equation, can anyone please help me?

error code:Traceback (most recent call last):
File "program1_MaxF.py", line 14, in 
solve(yVelocity*t-.5*g*t**2)
NameError: name 'solve' is not defined

Comment: Please post the full error traceback.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "program1_MaxF.py", line 14, in <module>
    solve(yVelocity*t-.5*g*t**2)
NameError: name 'solve' is not defined

Comment: Please post all tracebacks in your post and not in a comment.  Fwiw, you haven't imported solve

Comment: how do i import solve? and i just reposted it.

Comment: You haven't defined `solve`, and it's not clear what you expect that to do. There's no builtin `solve` function in the python standard library, and we can't guess what other library you might be expecting to use. If this is a homework assignment, perhaps you should check your notes for what libraries you're expected to be using in this class, or ask your instructor?

Comment: I have and I still can't figure it out and my teacher won't help me because he doesn't want to give me the answer. Is there anyway to make it solve the equation with something else. I'm kinda grasping at straws i've been working on this for so long and it's due in a hour and ive been working on it for over a day.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the formulas, you're calculating the new speed and position of an object given the starting velocity and travel time.

You probably want something like this:

```
def my_function(parameter):
    print(parameter)
    
my_function("Maxwell Filipe")
my_function("Program 1 Projectile Motion Formulae")
my_function("2/9/2020")
my_function("Program that will solve simple Projectile Motion Equations")
my_function("Choose the values for time, yVelocity, and xVelocity")

time = float(input('Time? '))
yVelocity = float(input('Y Vel? '))
xVelocity = float(input('X Vel? '))

g = 9.8
units='m/s'

import math
height = yVelocity*time-.5*g*time**2
distance = xVelocity*time
vspeed = yVelocity-g*time

print(f'Height={height} Distance={distance} YSpeed={vspeed}')
```